big unwanted spaces between sections
I am getting way to big vertical sections between sections only after adding
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

which I need in order to have vertical lines instead of indents for paragraphs.
My preamble is as follows:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsbsy, amsmath, multirow, hyperref, graphicx, setspace, float, natbib, url, booktabs, bm, amsmath, dsfont, titlesec}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=black, filecolor=black, linkcolor=black, urlcolor=black}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} 
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}



Welcome! try \usepackage{parskip} instead, which mostly avoids such side-effects.

Unrelated: left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm can be written more compactly as margin=2cm. And you are loading packages multiple times.

So you not only want “double spacing”, but also spaced paragraphs. The excess space after section titles is the least of your problems, I'm afraid.

To follow up on @campa's comment: citecolor=black, filecolor=black, linkcolor=black, urlcolor=black can be written more compactly as allcolors=black. In addition, instead of manipulating the low-level parameter \baselinestretch directly, do consider executing \usepackage{setspace} (which you actually already do) followed by \setstretch{1.5}.

As @cfr has already suggested in a comment, I also recommend that you replace
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

with
\usepackage[skip=1\baselineskip]{parskip}

I further recommend that you replace \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5} with \setstretch{1.5}. \setstretch is a macro provided by the setspace package. That way, the spacing in tables and footnotes won't needlessly get messed up too.


For the sake of comparison, here's the output that's generated if \setlength\parindent{0pt} \setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip} remains in effect:


\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, bm, dsfont}
\usepackage{multirow, graphicx, natbib} 
\usepackage{booktabs, lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\setstretch{1.5} 
\usepackage{xurl} % not 'url'
\usepackage[colorlinks, allcolors=black]{hyperref}

%\setlength\parindent{0pt} 
%\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}
\usepackage[skip=1\baselineskip]{parskip} % <-- new

\begin{document}
\stepcounter{section}
\section{Methodology}
\subsection{Treatment effects}
\lipsum[1][1-9]  % two short paragraphs of filler text

\lipsum[2][1-9]
\end{document}


When I see documents typeset like this, my eyes bleed.

@egreg - Mine do too...
